# Contents of str as a name of array

Tags: java, android

My problem seems simple, so hopefully I can find the answer quickly.
To summarize my code, I generate a random number between 1 & 2. With that I have a string `questionName` containing `easy1` or `easy2` (`"easy" + randomNum`) depending on the random number. I want to print the contents of `questionName` but instead of a string, get the array `easy1[0]` or `easy2[0]`.

```
public void generateQuestion() {
    int min = 1;
    int max = 2;


    Random r = new Random();
    int questionToBeSelected = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

    System.out.println(questionToBeSelected);

    String questionName = "easy" + questionToBeSelected;

    String[] easy1 = {
            "In The Phantom Menace, who are the first two characters on screen?", //Question, obviously
            "3", //The array child that is correct
            "Padme and Annie", //Answer 1
            "Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon Jinn", //Answer 2
            "Jar Jar Binks", //Answer 3
            "Annie and Obi-Wan" //Answer 4
    };

    String[] easy2 = {
            "Sample question",
            "2",
            "Sample answer",
            "Sample answer",
            "Sample answer",
            "Sample answer",
    };

    System.out.println(easy1[0]);

    TextView questionPlaceholder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_question);
    questionPlaceholder.setText(questionName[0]);  //   <-------- Problem :(

    String alreadyPlayedQuestions;
    String questionNumber;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please have a look at the following:

```
public void generateQuestion() {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 1;
    Random r = new Random();
    int questionToBeSelected = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    System.out.println(questionToBeSelected);
    String[] easy1 = {
            "In The Phantom Menace, who are the first two characters on screen?", //Question, obviously
            "3", //The array child that is correct
            "Padme and Annie", //Answer 1
            "Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon Jinn", //Answer 2
            "Jar Jar Binks", //Answer 3
            "Annie and Obi-Wan" //Answer 4
    };
    String[] easy2 = {
            "Sample question",
            "2", // array index that is correct
            "Sample answer",
            "Wrong answer1",
            "Wrong answer2",
            "Wrong answer3",
    };
    String[] questionName = new String[][]{easy1, easy2}[questionToBeSelected];
    System.out.println(easy1[0]);
    TextView questionPlaceholder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_question);
    System.out.println(questionName[0]);
    questionPlaceholder.setText(questionName[0]);  //   <-------- Problem :(
    String alreadyPlayedQuestions;
    String questionNumber;
}
```

Very little changes have been made to your method. Please tell me this is what you wanted to achieve or not.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to just store both arrays in another array and pick a random element from it:

```
int questionToBeSelected = r.nextInt(1);

String[] easy1 = {
        "In The Phantom Menace, who are the first two characters on screen?", //Question, obviously
        "3", //The array child that is correct
        "Padme and Annie", //Answer 1
        "Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon Jinn", //Answer 2
        "Jar Jar Binks", //Answer 3
        "Annie and Obi-Wan" //Answer 4
};

String[] easy2 = {
        "Sample question",
        "2",
        "Sample answer",
        "Sample answer",
        "Sample answer",
        "Sample answer",
};

String[][] easy = {easy1, easy2};

String[] selectedQuetion = easy[questionToBeSelected];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Whenever running this though, I always get `In the Phantom.....` printed, I would really like it to be random, not the same. Thank you.